# Remove items from the end of a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I have the following implementation of a LinkedList.

```
package assignment10;
// A linked list is a sequence of nodes with efficient
// element insertion and removal.
// This class contains a subset of the methods of the
// standard java.util.LinkedList class.

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class LinkedList {

    //nested class to represent a node
    private class Node {

        public Object data;
        public Node next;
    }

    //only instance variable that points to the first node.
    private Node first;

    // Constructs an empty linked list.
    public LinkedList() {
        first = null;
    }

    // Returns the first element in the linked list.
    public Object getFirst() {
        if (first == null) {
            NoSuchElementException ex
                    = new NoSuchElementException();
            throw ex;
        } else {
            return first.data;
        }
    }

    // Removes the first element in the linked list.
    public Object removeFirst() {
        if (first == null) {
            NoSuchElementException ex = new NoSuchElementException();
            throw ex;
        } else {
            Object element = first.data;
            first = first.next;  //change the reference since it's removed.
            return element;
        }
    }

    // Adds an element to the front of the linked list.
    public void addFirst(Object element) {
        //create a new node
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.data = element;
        newNode.next = first;
        //change the first reference to the new node.
        first = newNode;
    }

    // Returns an iterator for iterating through this list.
    public ListIterator listIterator() {
        return new LinkedListIterator();
    }

    /**
     * *******************************************************
     * Add your methods here
     * *******************************************************
     */
    public String toString() {
        String string;
        if (size() == 0) {
            string = "{ }";
        } else {
            string = "{ ";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            ListIterator iterator = listIterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                sb.append(String.valueOf(iterator.next())).append(" ");
            }
            sb.append("}");
            string = string.concat(sb.toString());
        }

        return string;
    }

    public int size() {
//          int size=0;
//          while(this.listIterator().hasNext()){
//              this.listIterator().next();
//              size++;
//          }
//          return size;
        int size = 0;
        ListIterator iterator = listIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();
            size++;
        }

        return size;
    }

    public void addElementAt(Object element, int index) {
        ListIterator listIterator = this.listIterator();
        int size = size();
        if (size == 0) {
            this.listIterator().add(element);
        } else {
            int i= 0;
            while(i<index-1){
                listIterator.next();
            }
            listIterator.add(element);
//            Node _head = new Node();
//            Node node = new Node();
//            node.data = element;
//            int ix = index - 1;
//            node.next = _head;
//
//            Node previous = _head;
//
//            for (int i = size - 1; i > ix; --i) {
//                previous = previous.next;
//            }
//
//            Node position = previous.next;
//
//            previous.next = node;
//            node.next = position;
//            ++size;
        }
    }

    public void addFewAtEnd(Object element, int howMany) {
        ListIterator listIterator = this.listIterator();
        int i=0;
        while(i<howMany){
           listIterator.add(element);
        }
    }

    public void removeLastFew(int howMany) {
        ListIterator listIterator = this.listIterator();
        int size = size();
        int i=0;
        if(howMany>0){
            if(howMany<size){
                while(i<size){
                    listIterator.next();
                }
                for(int removed=0;removed<howMany;removed++){
                    listIterator.remove();
                    listIterator.next();
                }
            } else {
                while(i<size){
                    listIterator.next();
                }
                for(int removed=0;removed<size;removed++){
                    listIterator.remove();
                    listIterator.next();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void removeAllOccurrences(Object stringToBeRemoved) {
         ListIterator listIterator = this.listIterator();
         while(listIterator.hasNext()){
             if(String.valueOf(listIterator.next()).equalsIgnoreCase(stringToBeRemoved.toString())){
                 listIterator.next();
             } else {
                 listIterator.next();
             }

         }
    }

    public void reverseLastFew(int howMany) {
        ListIterator listIterator = this.listIterator();
        int size = size();
        int i=0;
        if(howMany>0){
            if(howMany<size){
                LinkedList linkedList = new LinkedList();
                while(this.listIterator().hasNext()){
                    listIterator.next();
                }
                int count=0;
                while(count<howMany){
                    linkedList.listIterator().add(listIterator.next());
                    listIterator().remove();
                    listIterator.next();
                }

            } else {
                LinkedList linkedList = new LinkedList();
                 int count=0;
                while(count<size){
                    linkedList.listIterator().add(listIterator.next());
                    listIterator().remove();
                    listIterator.next();
                }
                count = 0;
                while(linkedList.listIterator().hasNext()){
                    if(count==0){
                        this.addFirst(linkedList.first);
                    } else {
                        this.addElementAt(linkedList.listIterator().next(), count);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //nested class to define its iterator
    private class LinkedListIterator implements ListIterator {

        private Node position; //current position
        private Node previous; //it is used for remove() method

        // Constructs an iterator that points to the front
        // of the linked list.
        public LinkedListIterator() {
            position = null;
            previous = null;
        }

        // Tests if there is an element after the iterator position.
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (position == null) //not traversed yet
            {
                if (first != null) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                if (position.next != null) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        // Moves the iterator past the next element, and returns
        // the traversed element's data.
        public Object next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                NoSuchElementException ex = new NoSuchElementException();
                throw ex;
            } else {
                previous = position; // Remember for remove

                if (position == null) {
                    position = first;
                } else {
                    position = position.next;
                }

                return position.data;
            }
        }

        // Adds an element before the iterator position
        // and moves the iterator past the inserted element.
        public void add(Object element) {
            if (position == null) //never traversed yet
            {
                addFirst(element);
                position = first;
            } else {
                //making a new node to add
                Node newNode = new Node();
                newNode.data = element;
                newNode.next = position.next;
                //change the link to insert the new node
                position.next = newNode;
                //move the position forward to the new node
                position = newNode;
            }
            //this means that we cannot call remove() right after add()
            previous = position;
        }

        // Removes the last traversed element. This method may
        // only be called after a call to the next() method.
        public void remove() {
            if (previous == position) //not after next() is called
            {
                IllegalStateException ex = new IllegalStateException();
                throw ex;
            } else {
                if (position == first) {
                    removeFirst();
                } else {
                    previous.next = position.next; //removing
                }
                //stepping back
                //this also means that remove() cannot be called twice in a row.
                position = previous;
            }
        }

        // Sets the last traversed element to a different value.
        public void set(Object element) {
            if (position == null) {
                NoSuchElementException ex = new NoSuchElementException();
                throw ex;
            } else {
                position.data = element;
            }
        }

    } //end of LinkedListIterator class
} //end of LinkedList class
```

And

```
package assignment10;
// The ListIterator interface allows access of a position in a linked list.
// This interface contains a subset of the methods of the
//  standard java.util.ListIterator interface. The methods for
//  backward traversal are not included.

public interface ListIterator
{
   //Move Moves the iterator past the next element.
   Object next();

   // Tests if there is an element after the iterator position.
   boolean hasNext();

   // Adds an element before the iterator position
   // and moves the iterator past the inserted element.
   void add(Object element);


   // Removes the last traversed element. This method may
   // only be called after a call to the next() method.
   void remove();

   // Sets the last traversed element to a different value.
   void set(Object element);
}
```

The method removeLastFew() is supposed to remove the specified number of items from the LinkedList at the end. How can I achieve this? At the moment, the method is not working.

Comment: Then you should probably fix it.  Maybe if you provided *any* details of the problem, and evidence that you have tried to solve it yourself, someone here could help you with that.

Comment: I have provided my implementation.

Comment: Which doesn't address a single one of the issues I raised.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here.

### Option 1:

This is the ugly and slow but easy.

Create a `removeLast()` and call it as many times as needed.

Of course, if you need this for a serious production, it will be too slow (but I doubt that, given the -non existent- complexity of the question). And if it is for an assignment and I were your professor you would most likely fail that one.

I guess you can do that by yourself.

### Option 2:

This might be the most efficient, and it's not hard either (but it's not really elegant either).

For every element `node` on the list, just check if **n**th element (being n the number of elements you want to erase) since `node` is null. If that is the case, set to null the reference to `node` (you have to store the previous Node, yes).

If you need to do it with the "remove" function, just use a simple loop once you have found the element described above.

### Option 3: (recursive).

This one is the one I like the most, but I have always been a big fan of recursion.

Create a function that goes all the way to the end, and then starts erasing.

Simple example (you will have to adapt it to your code, of course):

```
private int removeLast (int n, Node node) {
    int remaining = n;
    
    if (node.next != null) {
        remaining = removeLast (n, node.next);
    }

    if (remaining > 0) {
        remove(node);
        remaining--;
    }

    return remaining;
}
```

**NOTE:** I'm not sure if this would work, jsut made it from the top of my head, and didn't test it, just a pseudocode in case you want to do it this way (recommended Opt 2).

Answer (score 0):

I see probably bug here:

```
while(i<size) {
    listIterator.next();
}
```

there is missing increment of i. And fix the condition something like this:

```
i < (size-howMany)
```

Also when deleting item, you must firstly save the value from "next".

Answer (score 0):

a simple way

add a length property in your `LinkedList` then when you need to delete n nodes, go to the "length-n th" Node (some getNext()s in a while loop) and delete the rest!

don't forget to keep length valid